# how to save a result from postgres querys from different tables inside a function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have Postgres function that needs to iterate on an ARRAY of tables_name and should save the value that will be returned from the query each time to array.
maybe this is not correct way so if there is better ways to do it I'll be glad to know :)
I've try with format function to generate different queries each time.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_iter(tables_name text[],idd integer)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
declare
current_table text;
current_height integer :=0;
quer text;
heights integer[];
begin
    FOREACH current_table IN ARRAY $1
    LOOP
    quer:=format('SELECT height FROM %s WHERE %s.idd=$2', current_table);
    current_height:=EXECUTE quer;
    SELECT array_append(heights, current_height);
    
    END LOOP;
RAISE NOTICE '%', heights;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 1):

First off you desperately need to update your Postgres as version 9.1 is no longer supported and has not been for 5 years (Oct 2016). I would suggest going to v13 as it is the latest, but an absolute minimum to 10.12. That will still has slightly over a year (Nov 2022) before it looses support. So with that in mind.  
The statement `quer:=format('SELECT height FROM %s WHERE %s.idd=$2', current_table);` is invalid, it contains 2 format specifiers but only 1 argument. You could use the single argument by including the argument number on each specifier. So `quer:=format('SELECT height FROM %1s WHERE %1s.idd=$2', current_table);`. But that is not necessary as the 2nd is a table alias which need not be the table name and since you only have 1 table is not needed at all. I would however move the parameter ($2) out of the select and use a format specifiers/argument for it.  
The statement `current_height:=EXECUTE quer;` is likewise invalid, you cannot make the Right Val of assignment a select. For this you use the INTO option which follows the statement. `execute query into ...`.  
While `SELECT array_append(heights, current_height);` is a valid statement a simple assignment  `heights = heights || current_height;` seems easier (at least imho).  
Finally there a a couple omissions. Prior to running a dynamic SQL statement it is good practice to 'print' or log the statement before executing. What happens when the statement has an error. And why build a function to do all this work just to throw away the results, so instead of void return integer array (integer[]).  
So we arrive at:

```
create or replace function array_iter(tables_name text[],idd integer)
returns integer[]
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    current_table text;
    current_height integer :=0;
    quer text;
    heights integer[];
begin
    foreach current_table in array tables_name
    loop
        quer:=format('select height from %I where id=%s', current_table,idd);
        raise notice 'Running Query:: %',quer;     
        execute quer into current_height;
        heights = heights || current_height;   
    end loop;

    raise notice '%', heights;
    return heights;
exception 
    when others then
         raise notice 'Query failed:: SqlState:%, ErrorMessage:%', sqlstate,sqlerrm;
     raise;
end;
$$;
```

This does run on version as old as 9.5 (see [fiddle](http://%20https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=24c9c4ccbda7b77c5a1dbd019542a3cf)) although I cannot say that it runs on the even older 9.1.